# Objective-C problems performing math on an integer

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, integer

I have the following line of code which is running on a timer:

```
NSLog( @" seconds: %i, elapsedhours %f", [self elapsedSeconds], [self elapsedSeconds] / 3600);
```

It prints out:

```
seconds: 0, elapsedhours 0.000000
seconds: 1, elapsedhours 0.000000
seconds: 2, elapsedhours 0.000000
seconds: 3, elapsedhours 0.000000
```

I'm wondering why elapsed hours doesn't update?

Method for elapsedSeconds:

```
- (NSUInteger)elapsedSeconds;
{
    NSUInteger seconds = 0;
    if( ![self endDate] ) {
        seconds = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: [self startDate]];
        NSLog( @" startdate = %@ no end date %i", startDate, seconds );
    }
    else {
        seconds = [[self endDate] timeIntervalSinceDate: [self startDate]];
    }

    return seconds;
}
```

Anything else you guys/gals need to see?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), which doesn't calculate decimal parts although you then print it as a float.

You should divide it by `3600.0` if you want to see partial results..

Comment: Thanks guys that was it! I'm coming from the land of PHP where all this stuff is done magically. Difficult to get my head around these things.

Answer (score 0):

An integer divided by an integer is an integer.

So `1/3600` is `0`.

An integer divided by something else is something else

So `1/3600.0` is `0.00027777777`